# limit the date on 2 years in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck on a validation for my dates. For example, we are on `27-05-2020`, the user can enter a maximum date to 2 years in the form. Therefore, if the user enters on `29-05-2023`, an error message should appear.

I don't understand how to do this?

```js
function validation()
{
    var date_start = document.getElementById('date_start').value;

    const now = new Date(date_start)
    const oneYearFromNow = now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 2);

    if(now < oneYearFromNow) {
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Error date ! ";
        return false;
 
    }


    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" >
<br>
<label>Date start : </label>
<br>
<input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start">
<br>
<span id="date_startError"></span>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing current date with the date input by the user.

Also beware that when you did this:

`now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 2);`

you were also updating the year of the date saved in `now` variable, which is not what you expected if you want to compare it later.

Please check this snippet:

```js
function validation()
{
    var date_start = document.getElementById('date_start').value;
    const inputDate = new Date(date_start);
    
    const yearFromImputDate = inputDate.getFullYear();
    
    const now = new Date();
    const twoYearsFromNow = now.getFullYear() + 2;

    if(yearFromImputDate > twoYearsFromNow) {
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Error date ! ";
        return false;
    }
    
    console.log("Date is valid");
    return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" >
<br>
<label>Date start : </label>
<br>
<input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start">
<br>
<span id="date_startError"></span>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanations and your code., that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can set max on `input[type="date"]` to limit the maximum date. You can also set it using JS so that it can be dynamic. You can use what you have:

```
const now = new Date(date_start)
const oneYearFromNow = now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 2);
```

Then you can use `querySelector` to get the input element and `setAttribute` to set its max attribute to the value of `oneYearFormNow` converted to an `ISOString`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Input date type has a max attribute,

```
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="bday" min="1980-01-01" max="2000-01-01"/>
```

The calendar will be disabled once you reach the date mentioned within the max attribute

You can set max attribute from Javascript as follows:

```
var date_start = document.getElementById('date_start').value;

const now = new Date(date_start)

const fd = now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 2);

var nextTwoYears = fd.getDate() + '/' + (fd.getMonth()+1) + '/' +.fd.getFullYear() 

document.getElementById('date_start').setAttribute('max', nextTwoYears)
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to use javascrpit, it's an obligation.

Comment: You can update max attribute using javascript, give me a moment, il update the ans